# Floating Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a floating Fragment dynamically by inflating it and adding it to the Activity using FragmentTransaction.

When I"m adding it to the container (to a FrameLayout I created for that in the container) the all section under it is being pushed down and the all view changes (I want the view to look the same with or without the fragment).

I've looked at the implementation of the DialogFragment which floats over and do not change the view and I saw that it uses the: 
FragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId...) method with 0 as the containerViewId.
In the Google documentation it is just written that: "If 0, it will not be placed in a container". When I put 0 in my containerViewId and removed the FrameLayout from the view the Fragment didn't appear.

Comment: You should use [android-fragments] only. Don't use `[fragment]` for android questions... people will be more likely to see your question if you only use one, trust me :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're facing comes from the fact that you add the floating fragment to a `FrameLayout` that is a child to the already present layout which will, as you already seen, modify the current layout to make room for the new fragment. For example if your current layout is something like this(this is just an example):

```
<LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/here_add_floating_fragment"/>
    <the rest of the layout file with the content that should hold its position />
</LinearLayout>
```

If the floating fragment is added to a `FrameLayout` like in a layout like the one above then the rest of the views will indeed be moved to make room.

To prevent this you'll have to modify your layout so the `FrameLayout` will hold your current layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/here_add_floating_fragment"> 
      <LinearLayout>
          <the rest of the layout file with the content that should hold its position />
      </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, when you'll add the new fragment the current `Views` will stay in place and the fragment will appear above as the `FrameLayout` stack its children.